# Desired count vs MinTask in ECS Service

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I have a ECS service and Task definition that has MinTasks set to 2, and MaxTasks set to 4 and Desired count set to 1 which I thought means that the service always has at least two tasks.

When the Service was first deployed through cloudformation it brought up 2 tasks as expected. However when it was redeployed (service was updated) it brought up only 1 task.

Why is this? Why did it not bring up 2 tasks as before? Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

There are at least 3 services involved including Cloudformation, ECS and Service Autoscaling. Note that Cloudformation doesn't always play well with ECS. Having said that your set up isn't right to begin with. Your Desired count should always be greater or equal to the min and less than or equal to the max tasks. If you try to set your desired count below the min tasks, Console won't even let you do this.